# When I open text documents, they immediately print?

Tags: windows-7, printing, text-editing, documents

Every time I open a text (.txt) document on my PC (Windows 7 Ultimate x64), it immediately begins printing on my default printer.

*What is happening and how do I turn it off?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you have something like a `/p` in the file association since running `notepad /p filename.txt` will immediately print the file on the default printer.

```
C:\>assoc .txt
.txt=txtfile

C:\>ftype txtfile
txtfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

Of course this depends on exactly how you "open a text (.txt) document", For example, if you mean you run MS Word and use it's `File, Open` dialogue, you probably have a different problem.

---

EDIT

`assoc` and `ftype` provide an incomplete means of editing registry entries. My PC has under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`

```
\txtfile\shell\open\command    %SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.exe %1"
\txtfile\shell\print\command   %SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.exe /p %1"
```

(The key name and type are `(Default)` and `REG_EXPAND_SZ` respectively.)

There may have been some incorrect values (or missing entries) that cause the described problem.

Using `ftype` and `assoc` to attempt to correct this obviously carries fewer risks than editing the registry directly.

Comment: I "open" a txt file by double-clicking on it or right-clicking and choosing Open.

Comment: Here's the output of the commands you noted... c:\>assoc .txt => .txt=txtfile AND c:\>ftype txtfile => File type 'txtfile' not found or no open command associated with it.

Comment: Try `ftype txtfile="%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1"`

Comment: YES! that last command set the ftype (I checked with the command `ftype txtfile`) and when I opened a txt file, Windows asked me to associate it with a program. I chose Notepad. and it opened normally!

Answer (score 3):

Delete this key from the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile\
```

Right click on a .txt file, choose Open With > Notepad. All will be okay.

Comment: This answer of deleting the registry key and then opening Notepad worked perfectly for me. All I would say is make sure it is the `txtfile` you delete, not the `txt` one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel (icon view) Default Programs, then click "associate a file type or protocol with a program"

Scroll down to .txt , it should be associated with Notepad, is it?

If it is not, double click it and select Notepad

.

Comment: It is set to Notepad.

Comment: Does the test document open, then it starts printing? Try updating your printer software to the latest version.

Comment: How about changing it to another program like Wordpad, then setting it back to Notepad?

Comment: I tried cycling the associated program, it auto-prints still.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my home PC (what's going on!?) and the FTYPE command that [RedGrittyBrick](https://superuser.com/questions/234896/when-i-open-text-documents-they-immediately-print-help/234973#234973) suggested did not work this time. I had to modify the registry manually. I had to [modify the type](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/17ed07ec-fad3-4548-802a-3afb3edb9b21/) of the registry key using the command line.

```
reg.exe add <key> /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "<value>"
```